# Getting list of links from Google News

Tags: python

I am using Python's BeautifulSoup to get Google News links as a list. Here's what I got so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
#url is just some google link, not to worried about being able to search from Python code
url = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1526&bih=778&tbm=nws&q=amazon&oq=amazon&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.1377.2289.0.2359.7.7.0.0.0.0.116.508.5j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.5.430.0.19SoRsczxCA"
#this part of the code avoids error 403, we need to identify ourselves
browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':browser,}
#getting our html
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
#looking for links and adding them up as a list
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
list=(re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
print(list)
```

My question is: Why won't some links work? For instance:

[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com.mx/amazon-la-plataforma-changarro/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWk4aC05_UAhXo7YMKHTinD8QQqQIIFigAMAI&usg=AFQjCNH0PrZqIWgZsrLFQDy-nQ8WGCIUAw)
[El Financiero](http://www.elfinanciero.com.mx/mercados/acciones-de-amazon-alcanzan-los-mil-dolares.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWk4aC05_UAhXo7YMKHTinD8QQ-AsIGSgBMAI&usg=AFQjCNExYcdWsaE3bToPy4WRmQ8adyrxgg)
[El Mundo](http://www.elmundo.es/economia/empresas/2017/05/31/592df718268e3e630d8b457e.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWk4aC05_UAhXo7YMKHTinD8QQ-AsIGigCMAI&usg=AFQjCNEp9aRcEWp7QJ5K3ScvD85D7GcIJQ)
[Cnet](https://www.cnet.com/es/noticias/amazon-y-itunes-descuento-peliculas/&sa=u&ved=0ahukewiwk4ac05_uahxo7ymkhtind8qqqqiihygamam&usg=afqjcnh7k7soqtxreeurg9fqc6eby3f7ba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1526&bih=778&tbm=nws&q=amazon&oq=amazon&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.1377.2289.0.2359.7.7.0.0.0.0.116.508.5j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.5.430.0.19SoRsczxCA"
browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers = {'User-Agent':browser,}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
links = soup.findAll("a")

l = []

for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    l.append(re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))[0])

print(l)
```

Some notes:

- Never use `list` as a variable name! This is reserved words for the list type!
- If you want the links. you should append them to your list, not override your variable! use the `list.append` method for this purpose.
- The re.split returns list, you should pick the first variable in it (That's why I used the `[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

All the links that you have mentioned shows '404 Page Not Found' error when opened in browser. Hence the links are broken or dead. You can refer this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

You need to check the url's [response status code](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) before parsing the page content with BeautifulSoup.

```
...
page = requests.get(url)
if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    ....
```